# firefox code modules components.utils.import

Tags: firefox-addon

Does anyone know of an example/sample .xpi file that uses Components.utils.import to load a custom code module? I cannot get it to work. Basically I cannot get it to work when I package to a .jar file. Is this a limitation to use code modules?

A sample would be really helpful, probably with the code below.

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["foo", "bar"];

function foo() {
  return "foo";
}

var bar = {
  name : "bar",
  size : 3
};
```

Comment: How do you load the module? Have you set up your `chrome.manifest` accordingly?

Comment: I am using FF 4.0, hence I use chrome url to load the module. I could load the module just fine if I don't package the addon into "jar" file. Even after packaging, when I type in the url chrome://myaddon/content/module.jsm, the file opens in the browser just fine. So the problem is just with import and packaging. In fact, I tried the chrome.manifest resource approach also, it didn't work. I could open the resource file from the url but couldn't import.

Answer (score 0):

Has passed some time, but here you have:

```
// modules/module.jsm file
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["myUniqueCode"];

// wrap your code
var myUniqueCode = {
    foo : function() {
        return "foo";
    },
    bar : {
        name : "bar",
        size : 3
    }
}

// load module where you need it
Components.utils.import("resource://your_addon_name/module.jsm"); 

// use myUniqueCode.foo()
```

As @felix-kling recommends:

```
// add to your chrome.manifest file
resource    your_addon_name     modules/
```